# Add the value of two columns in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I have a code that something like the one below

```
SELECT SUM(points_1) AS total_points_1, SUM(points_2) AS total_points_2,

       total_points_1 +
       CASE 
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 50
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 100
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 200 AND 300 THEN 200
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 300 AND 400 THEN 300
         ELSE 500
       END AS another_row_1,

       total_points_2 +
       CASE 
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 50
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 100
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 200 AND 300 THEN 200
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 300 AND 400 THEN 300
         ELSE 500
       END AS another_row_2,

FROM  `table`
```

My goal is to add the result of `another_row_1` and `another_row_2`

I've tried doing the line below right after the `END AS another_row_2,` but did not work

**SUM(another_row_1 + another_row_2) AS total_sum**

Comment: `another_row_1` and `another_row_2` are column projections, not rows at all. You thus just need to add them with the `+` operator

Comment: How are you gonna do that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all to decrease the clutter and improve maintainability I'd suggest to wrap point recalculation logic (the one that implemented with `CASE`) into a function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION add_points(_points INT)
RETURNS INT
RETURN 
  _points + 
  CASE 
    WHEN _points BETWEEN  50 AND  99 THEN 50
    WHEN _points BETWEEN 100 AND 199 THEN 100
    WHEN _points BETWEEN 200 AND 299 THEN 200
    WHEN _points BETWEEN 300 AND 399 THEN 300
    ELSE 500
  END;
```

**Note:** you might need to change the data type from `INT` to `DECIMAL(n,m)` (according to your actual data type of columns `points_1` and `points_2`)

Now the query would look like

```sql
SELECT total_points_1,
       total_points_2,
       another_total_1,
       another_total_2,
       another_total_1 + another_total_2 total_sum
  FROM
(
  SELECT SUM(points_1) total_points_1, 
         SUM(points_2) total_points_2,
         add_points(SUM(points_1)) another_total_1,
         add_points(SUM(points_2)) another_total_2
    FROM table1
) q
```

Sample output:

```
| TOTAL_POINTS_1 | TOTAL_POINTS_2 | ANOTHER_TOTAL_1 | ANOTHER_TOTAL_2 | TOTAL_SUM |
|----------------|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------|
|            165 |            386 |             265 |             686 |       951 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebb88/1)** demo

Comment: @user3135626 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it in an inner query

```
SELECT (res.another_row_1 + res.another_row_2) AS total_sum FROM
(
SELECT SUM(points_1) AS total_points_1, SUM(points_2) AS total_points_2,

       total_points_1 +
       CASE 
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 50
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 100
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 200 AND 300 THEN 200
         WHEN total_points_1 BETWEEN 300 AND 400 THEN 300
         ELSE 500
       END AS another_row_1,

       total_points_2 +
       CASE 
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 50
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 100 AND 200 THEN 100
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 200 AND 300 THEN 200
         WHEN total_points_2 BETWEEN 300 AND 400 THEN 300
         ELSE 500
       END AS another_row_2,

FROM  `table`
) AS res
```

Comment: There is no need in `SUM()` function in the outer query and you **have to** give an alias to the subquery (derived table)

Comment: @user3135626 it's all there what else do you need ?